# How do I make a PATCH request in Python?

Tags: python, http, patch, httplib

Is there a way to make a request using the `PATCH` HTTP method in Python?

I tried using httplib, but it doesn't accept PATCH as method param.

Comment: Did you mean PUT? PUSH is not a valid request method for HTTP

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python), it uses PUT on that post, I guess you can use PUSH as a verb and wont give you trouble, still you should use PUT instead of PUSH

Comment: Sorry, people, I typed the wrong method name, I edited the question o.O

Comment: Cat Plus Plus: yes, there is a PATCH method. dave: PUSH is "valid". There's a difference between "valid" and "registered".

Comment: Cat Plus Plus: here about PATCH method http://www.innoq.com/blog/st/2010/03/rfc_5789_patch_method_for_http.html

It's ironic that Google support and use it in APIs but GAE urlfetch doesn't work with it.

Comment: salesforce.com REST API requires use of the PATCH method for updating objects, so I am looking for this too, so I can update objects from Google App Engine http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm

Answer (score 25):

With [Requests](http://python-requests.org), making [PATCH requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.patch) is very simple:

```
import requests

r = requests.patch('http://httpbin.org/patch')
```

Comment: How do I log `r`. Should I just do `self.log.info('Response: %s' % r)`?

Comment: how can i pass string json data into this ?

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan over here are better answers [Post JSON using Python Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests#26344315)

Answer (score 16):

Seems to work in 2.7.1 as well.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> request = urllib2.Request('http://google.com')
>>> request.get_method = lambda: 'PATCH'
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(request)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Great information.  This is a simple little hack to make urllib2 use PATCH instead of POST.  I don't know why PATCH hasn't been implemented as an option yet.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this in Python 3, and it seemed to work (but I don't have a server handy that supports the `PATCH` request type):

```
>>> import http.client
>>> c = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
>>> r = c.request("PATCH", "/index.html")
>>> print(r.status, r.reason)
405 Method Not Allowed
```

I'm assuming that the `HTTP 405` is coming from the server and that it is "not allowed".

By the way, thanks for showing me the cool [PATCH method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) in HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try that later and mark as accepted. GitHub API accepted POST instead of PATCH, but I will give that a try and keep this for future.

Answer (score 2):

It is incredibly simple with [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/):

```
import httplib2

http = httplib2.Http()
http.request("http://www.google.com", "PATCH", <patch content>)
```

It supports Python 2.3 or later (including 3.x) and works beautifully!