# How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, cherrypy

I need to POST a JSON from a client to a server. I'm using Python 2.7.1 and simplejson. The client is using Requests. The server is CherryPy. I can GET a hard-coded JSON from the server (code not shown), but when I try to POST a JSON to the server, I get "400 Bad Request".

Here is my client code:

```
data = {'sender':   'Alice',
    'receiver': 'Bob',
    'message':  'We did it!'}
data_json = simplejson.dumps(data)
payload = {'json_payload': data_json}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080", data=payload)
```

Here is the server code.

```
class Root(object):

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content
        print self.content  # this works

    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return simplejson.dumps(self.content)

    def POST(self):
        self.content = simplejson.loads(cherrypy.request.body.read())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I was using a stripped down version of an example straight out of the [documentation](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/REST.html).

Comment: My comment still stands - CherryPy does not call class `__init__` methods with a `content` argument (and does not claim to in the link you supply).  In the detailed example they have, the user supplies the code that calls `__init__` and provides the arguments, which we have not seen here so I have no idea what state your object is in when your `# this works` comment is relevant.

Comment: Are you asking to see the line where the instance is created?

Comment: yeah, I was trying to start up your example in order to test it, and I wasn't sure how you were instantiating it.

Comment: The code has changed. I'm now creating it without the extra argument. `cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/', conf)`.

Comment: Alternatively, If you use a tool like _Postman_ to test your API calls, you can generate code snippet. Like snippets in Python that uses the `requests` package. 
[Postman documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/)

Answer (score 1762, accepted):

Starting with Requests version 2.4.2, you can use the [`json=` parameter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) (which takes a dictionary) instead of `data=` (which takes a string) in the call:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json={"key": "value"})
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.json()
{'args': {},
 'data': '{"key": "value"}',
 'files': {},
 'form': {},
 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*',
             'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
             'Connection': 'close',
             'Content-Length': '16',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Host': 'httpbin.org',
             'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.4.3 CPython/3.4.0',
             'X-Request-Id': 'xx-xx-xx'},
 'json': {'key': 'value'},
 'origin': 'x.x.x.x',
 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/post'}
```

Comment: Setting this to the accepted answer since this is more idiomatic as of 2.4.2. Keep in mind, for crazy unicode, this may not work.

Comment: I saw an example of this that took the dict object and performed json.dumps(object) before sending. Don't do this...it messes up your JSON. The above is perfect..you can pass it a python object and it turns into perfect json.

Comment: @MydKnight looking at the source code, Requests sets the content type then does [`json.dumps(your_json)`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/4f6c0187150af09d085c03096504934eb91c7a9e/requests/models.py#L469) and converts the result from a `str` to `bytes`.

Comment: I logged into my account especially to give you +1 for this. Thanks. I was stuck for a couple of hours until I saw you could specify json=dict  It' a script for Linode DNS API that I am working on. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also should note, that in order to add authentication, you can easily add the `auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pass)` to the params.

Comment: Before I found this answer I had also to use ```data=json.dumps(...)``` but without ```Content-type: application/json``` in the header it wouldn't work. This ```json=...``` thing works perfect.

Comment: Server sends me absolutely different results with using `data=` and `json=`. Thanks!

Comment: In my the latest requests version the logic is to favor data over json in case of both value are provided. It is not a warning!!! https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/b8be93a721792deeadd2f498b8f77cf610e7765f/src/requests/models.py#L501-L515 and https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/b8be93a721792deeadd2f498b8f77cf610e7765f/src/requests/models.py#L557-L570 and here you see it doesn't automatically print body based on content-type (which I thought).

Comment: Using parameter json= we don't need to set the header Content-Type: Application/Json

Answer (score 545):

It turns out I was missing the header information. The following works:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080"
data = {'sender': 'Alice', 'receiver': 'Bob', 'message': 'We did it!'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Good catch - I saw your `application/json` in `GET` and somehow missed that you hadn't provided it on the request.  You may also need to make sure that you return something from `POST` or you might get a `500`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be necessary. When I print `r`, I get `<Response [200]>`.

Comment: How do I retrieve this json at the server side ?

Comment: r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080')
    c = r.content
    result = simplejson.loads(c)

Comment: Little heads up before using `json.dumps` here. The `data` parameter of `requests` works fine with dictionaries. No need for converting to a string.

Comment: This was the best answer for me as requests' built in json support uses Python's built in json support which could not handle my object types.  So I needed to use jsonpickle and manually set the media type to json

Comment: yeah, json.dumps(data) is a very efficient and amazing way to do it.

Comment: Is `headers=headers` necessary?

Comment: @lolololol ol It's necessary. You are setting an argument for the function/method you're calling. In this case the function/method is named post(). The left side of the assignment operator `=` is the parameter name some dev defined (e.g.  `def post(some_param0, headers, ...):`). The righthand side of the assignment operator (i.e. assignment value) is the variable *you* defined (e.g. `headers = { ... }`) that also just happens to be called `headers` in this example. You could rename the right side of the assignment (e.g. the assignment value) to whatever you like!

Answer (score 99):

From requests 2.4.2 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), the "json" parameter is supported. No need to specify "Content-Type". So the shorter version:

```
requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json={'test': 'cheers'})
```

Answer (score 80):

Which parameter between `data` / `json` / `files` you need to use depends on a request header named [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) (you can check this through the developer tools of your browser).

When the `Content-Type` is **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**, use `data=`:

```py
requests.post(url, data=json_obj)
```

When the `Content-Type` is **`application/json`**, you can either just use `json=` or use `data=` and set the `Content-Type` yourself:

```py
requests.post(url, json=json_obj)
```

```py
requests.post(url, data=jsonstr, headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})
```

When the `Content-Type` is **`multipart/form-data`**, it's used to upload files, so use `files=`:

```py
requests.post(url, files=xxxx)
```

Comment: +1. If you're using `curlify` to see the request made from the response, the content type header will not be set unless you follow these instructions.

`print(curlify.to_curl(project.request))`

Comment: The key realization is that every parameter will perform automagic serialization without regard for the current value of the `Content-Type` header. Consequently, `data=json_obj` is basically always incorrect; the value must be stringified first, either explicitly by the caller or implicitly via the `json` parameter.

Answer (score 50):

The better way is：

```
url = "http://xxx.xxxx.xx"
data = {
    "cardno": "6248889874650987",
    "systemIdentify": "s08",
    "sourceChannel": 12
}
resp = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
headers = {"charset": "utf-8", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
url = 'http://localhost:PORT_NUM/FILE.php'

r = requests.post(url, json=YOUR_JSON_DATA, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 9):

Works perfectly with python 3.5+

client:

```
import requests
data = {'sender':   'Alice',
    'receiver': 'Bob',
    'message':  'We did it!'}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080", json={'json_payload': data})
```

server:

```
class Root(object):

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content
        print self.content  # this works

    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return simplejson.dumps(self.content)

    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def POST(self):
        self.content = cherrypy.request.json
        return {'status': 'success', 'message': 'updated'}
```

Comment: Note/reminder: the `json` arg automatically adds the `content-type` header for `POST` in newer versions of Python.

Answer (score 8):

With current `requests` you can pass in any data structure that dumps to valid JSON , with the `json` parameter, not just dictionaries (as falsely claimed by the answer by Zeyang Lin).

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json=[1, 2, {"a": 3}])
```

this is particularly useful if you need to order elements in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


req = request.json
if not req :
    req = request.form
req['value']
```

Answer (score -1):

It always recommended that we need to have the ability to read the JSON file and parse an object as a request body. We are not going to parse the raw data in the request so the following method will help you to resolve it.

```
def POST_request():
    with open("FILE PATH", "r") as data:
        JSON_Body = data.read()
    response = requests.post(url="URL", data=JSON_Body)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```