# How to get POSTed JSON in Flask?

Tags: python, json, post, flask

I'm trying to build a simple API using Flask, in which I now want to read some POSTed JSON. I do the POST with the Postman Chrome extension, and the JSON I POST is simply `{"text":"lalala"}`. I try to read the JSON using the following method:

```
@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message(uuid):
    content = request.json
    print content
    return uuid
```

On the browser it correctly returns the UUID I put in the GET, but on the console, it just prints out `None` (where I expect it to print out the `{"text":"lalala"}`. Does anybody know how I can get the posted JSON from within the Flask method?

Answer (score 625, accepted):

First of all, the `.json` attribute is a property that delegates to the [`request.get_json()` method](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.get_json), which documents why you see `None` here.

You need to set the request content type to `application/json` for the `.json` property and `.get_json()` method (with no arguments) to work as either will produce `None` otherwise. See the [Flask `Request` documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.json):

> The parsed JSON data if `mimetype` indicates JSON (`application/json`, see [`.is_json`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.is_json)).

You can tell `request.get_json()` to skip the content type requirement by passing it the `force=True` keyword argument.

Note that if an *exception* is raised at this point (possibly resulting in a 400 Bad Request response), your JSON *data* is invalid. It is in some way malformed; you may want to check it with a JSON validator.

Comment: I thought when an *exception* is raised at this point it should more likely result in a 500 Internal Error response, isn't it?

Comment: @iBug It's an old question, but the answer is that it should result in a 400, because if the request wasn't malformed, the exception wouldn't be raised.

Comment: @iBug: badly formed JSON in a request is not a server error, it is an error on the part of the client, making it a 400 class error.

Answer (score 204):

For reference, here's complete code for how to send json from a Python client:

```
import requests
res = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api/add_message/1234', json={"mytext":"lalala"})
if res.ok:
    print(res.json())
```

The "json=" input will automatically set the content-type, as discussed here: [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

And the above client will work with this server-side code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message(uuid):
    content = request.json
    print(content['mytext'])
    return jsonify({"uuid":uuid})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Answer (score 94):

This is the way I would do it and it should be

```
@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message(uuid):
    content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    # print(content) # Do your processing
    return uuid
```

With `silent=True` set, the `get_json` function will fail silently when trying to retrieve the json body. By default this is set to `False`. If you are always expecting a json body (not optionally), leave it as `silent=False`.

Setting `force=True` will ignore the
`request.headers.get('Content-Type') == 'application/json'` check that flask does for you. By default this is also set to `False`.

See [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/).

I would strongly recommend leaving `force=False` and make the client send the `Content-Type` header to make it more explicit.

Comment: I cannot see any case where it would make sense to some times post valid json and other times invalid json. Sounds like two different end points

Comment: Like I said, if an endpoint takes "optional" json body, you can use `silent=True`. Yes this is possible, and I do use it. Its really based on how you design your API to be consumed. If there is no case like that for your endpoint, just remove `silent=True` or explicitly set it to `False`.

Answer (score 35):

Assuming you've posted valid JSON with the `application/json` content type, `request.json` will have the parsed JSON data.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/echo', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
   return jsonify(request.json)
```

Comment: To add to this answer the request you could send to this endpoint could be `response = request.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello', json={"foo": "bar"})`. Following this running `response.json()` should return `{'foo': 'bar'}`

Answer (score 16):

For all those whose issue was from the ajax call, here is a full example :

Ajax call : the key here is to use a `dict` and then `JSON.stringify`

```
    var dict = {username : "username" , password:"password"};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", //localhost Flask
        data : JSON.stringify(dict),
        contentType: "application/json",
    });
```

And on server side :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",  methods = ['POST'])
def hello():
    print(request.get_json())
    return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'} 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Note, for some reason it won't work if the dict is defined as const, e.g., `const foo = {hello: "world"}`.

Answer (score 12):

If you use `force=True`, it will ignore the content type of the request and try to parse the body as JSON regardless.

```py
request.get_json(force=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

You may note that `request.json` or `request.get_json()` works only when the `Content-type: application/json` has been added in the header of the request. If you are unable to change the client request configuration, so you can get the body as json like this:

```
data = json.loads(request.data)
```

Comment: This worked for me, when trying to write google cloud function for dialogflow webhook as request is being sent as body in JSON format

Answer (score 5):

To give another approach.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/service', methods=['POST'])
def service():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    text = data.get("text",None)
    if text is None:
        return jsonify({"message":"text not found"})
    else:
        return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following codes can be used：

```
@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message(uuid):
  content = request.json['text']
  print content
  return uuid
```

Here is a screenshot of me getting the json data:

[image]

You can see that what is returned is a dictionary type of data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have posted valid JSON,

```
@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message(uuid):
    content = request.json
    print content['uuid']
    # Return data as JSON
    return jsonify(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though all the answers I encounter here are right. There is something that I think it should be done as better practice. Here is how I would write it.

```
from flask import app, request, Flask, jsonify


@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_message(uuid):
    
    # Check if the request method is POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # content will return eather parse data as JSON
        # Or None incase there is no data
        content = request.get_json()
        print(content)
        # The content could be displayed in html page if serialized as json
        return jsonify(content) # Return null if there is content

    # if it is only get request then just return uuid
    return uuid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "uuid":1212121212,
  "text":"lalala",
  "comment":"",
  "signed_on":"2022-11-07 00:03:00"
}
```

> you can sent the above data as json and get it in flask application using request.json

```
from flask import request, Blueprint,flash,json

@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def testing(uuid):
    sync_data = request.json    
    josn_data = json.dumps(sync_data ,default =str)
    return josn_data
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `force` attribute as `True` in `get_json()` method to resolve this issue.

```
request.get_json(force = True)
```