# Python Flask App route not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restful

I am not able to get the http://127.0.0.1:5000/user1 Url from the browser every time it gives 404 and for the http://127.0.0.1:5000 it gives old output which I have tried (some other string "Hello flask") instead of "hello world"
I have tried closing my IDE and trying again even I have created another project but the problem still persist

Thanks in advance!

```
#imports
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'hello world!'

#add users to collection "app_users"
@app.route('/user1',methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    if not request.json or not 'email_id' in request.json:
       abort(404)
    print("processing")
    insert(request)
    return flask.jsonify({'status': "inserted successfully"}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you restarting the server when reloading `@app.route('/')`? Also, try clearing your cache. With Chrome, you can do that by hitting SHIFT + F5.

`@app.route('/user1', methods=['POST'])` moves to abort since you are not posting anything in your view. What exactly are you trying to do in this route?

Also, while developing, I recommend running app run with the debug parameter:

`app.run(debug=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the port in `app.run()`

`app.run(debug=True, 
         host='0.0.0.0', 
         port=9000, 
         threaded=True)`

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue. Sometimes there might installation issues I guess.

In my case I just pip uninstalled flask and reinstalled and it worked fine ;)

To pip uninstall use :

```
pip uninstall flask
```

and check whether the servers aren't working, it obviously shouldn't then reinstall by

```
pip install flask
```

;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old and what I say may not answer this question in particular, but my problem was that I was forgetting to add the `@` before the `app.route`. The correct way is: `@app.route`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you submitting a form with the parameter (email_id) you set?  Also, make sure you are submitting the form with Content-Type: application/json - otherwise, request.json will be empty.  You can also use `request.get_json(force=True)`, but this is not recommended.  (See [How to get POSTed json in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask))