# Flask request.get_json() returning None when valid json data sent via post request

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

Building an app using flask. The app uses a table structure to display data. Part of its functionality is collecting the data from user specified table rows. To do this I have placed a button on each row that executes some js. The js collects the information from the row, uses JSON.stringify() to convert to json object and the issues the post request to the relevant flask url.

Logging the value of the jsonified object to the browser console from js file shows it is correctly formed. The post request contacts the correct route however the request.get_json() function returns a value of None in the method of that route.

I have set up a seperate route in flask for testing. Here is the relevant code

from javascript

```
    function do_some_work(e) {
        var row_data = get_table_row_data(e);
        row_data = JSON.stringify(row_data);
        console.log(row_data);
        $.post("test", row_data);
    }
```

get_table_row_data() simply returns an object with key:value pairs. The log shows the data is correctly formatted json.

And here is the python code

```
#TODO
@application.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    data = request.get_json()
    print("data is "+format(data))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Here data is coming up as None

any help much appreciated

Comment: If I understand correctly, the referred post 'How to get POSTed json in Flask?' was asking users to use get_json(), which is what the author was doing and turned out not working. It didn't seem to be a duplicated question to me.

Comment: The canonical has 775k+ views and 15+ answers that cover virtually every aspect of POSTing JSON in Flask, with and without jQuery. [The author themselves agreed it was a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010415/flask-request-get-json-returning-none-when-valid-json-data-sent-via-post-reque#comment85027055_49010614). For future visitors--please just [check out the canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask/)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `request.json` it will return a dictionary of the JSON data. To get a value you use `request.json.get('value_name')`. So your route will be like this

```
#TODO
@application.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    data = request.json
    print("data is " + format(data))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: solved. Its always going to be something stupid like that. Thanks very much

Comment: no problem, glad it solved your problem

Comment: ugh, my bad. Problem is still there and the same

Comment: still returning None
    data = request.json
    print('Data is '+format(data))

Comment: first add an if statement to check if it's a post request `if request.method == 'POST'` then try getting a single value from the json data with `request.json.get('data_in_json')`

Comment: yes it is a post request. trying to get a single value from the json data throws the following error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: also in your request, you should set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` else it'll return `None`. And sorry, you can use the `request.get_json(force=False)` to get it even if the header is not set

Comment: data = request.get_json(force=True) <--solved the issue. Thanks again folks. And whoever downvoted is correct. This is a duplicate question. Apologies

Comment: @PhilipButler to elaborate a little: 'force – if set to True the mimetype is ignored', so the call you're making either does not include a MIME type or the wrong one. You can either set the correct MIME type in your request ('application/json') or set 'force' to 'True', but then you need to be sure it is indeed JSON you're receiving.

Comment: Thanks, Philip. I was also facing the same issue. Adding force = True solved my issue :)