# Object of type 'RepeatedCompositeContainer' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Using Google Client Library interacting with the vision library.

I have a function to detect labels from an image.

**GoogleVision.py**

```
import os

from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson


class GoogleVision():

    def detectLabels(self, uri):

        client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
        image = types.Image()
        image.source.image_uri = uri

        response = client.label_detection(image=image)
        labels = response.label_annotations

        return labels
```

I have an api to call this function.

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import request
from flask import json
from util.GoogleVision import GoogleVision

import os


class Vision(Resource):

    def get(self):

        return {"message": "API Working"}

    def post(self):

        googleVision = GoogleVision()

        req = request.get_json()

        url = req['url']

        result = googleVision.detectLabels(url)

        return result
```

However, it does not return the result and errors with the following

> TypeError: Object of type 'RepeatedCompositeContainer' is not JSON
>   serializable

Comment: "RepeatedCompositeContainer" comes from "protobuf" and as far as I can see, you are not using `MessageToJson`. Here you can see a [question](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3485#issuecomment-307797562) where it was recommended to use it or use dictionaries. Also, I saw this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask) to get json from Flask.

Comment: MessageToJson did not work either, there are questions about this that already exist.

Comment: @AkashJobanputra i ended up doing a for loop over the result and creating my own object

Comment: Would be nice if @Iñigo if you could provide a working solution.

Comment: @Kay I found the solution here, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3485#issuecomment-406194079

Comment: @Kay do you still face this problem?

Answer (score 6):

This question was answered in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/70#issuecomment-307797562), which might help to resolve your issue.

**The error you encountered is**

```
TypeError: Object of type 'RepeatedCompositeContainer' is not JSON serializable
```

**Below is the solution provided in the GitHub thread**

- The Vision library returns plain protobuf objects, which can be serialized to JSON using:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
serialized = MessageToJson(original)
```

- You can also go to dictionaries using something like [protobuf3-to-dict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf3-to-dict/).

Comment: This causes an error `AttributeError: 'google._upb._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'`

Comment: That's because you are not passing the root message to MessageToJson.

Comment: You might have to do `MessageToJson(response._pb)`