# When returning variables in cloud function I get: TypeError: Object of type RepeatedComposite is not JSON serializable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

For some context I am building a cloud function to handle calls to a deployed Vertex AI model. Everything seems to work fine until it comes to returning the actual value.

When I copy and paste that exact dictionary {'fox':[0.002073,..]} as such:
Example code that works:

```
@functions_framework.http
def hello_get(request):
    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    ...
    # Get prediction using Vertex AI endpoint
    instance = get_prediction(request_json['instances'])
    "Example output is a list of 512 float values"

    output = zip(request_json['instances'], instance)
    sorted_output = sorted(output, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    f_output = dict(sorted_output) # not used!!
    return {'fox': [0.00207372033, -0.0550017245, -0.040824689...]}
```

It doesn't crash, yet if I have the variable assigned such as:

```
out = {'fox': [0.00207372033, -0.0550017245, -0.040824689...]}
return out
```

I get the error "TypeError: Object of type RepeatedComposite is not JSON serializable"

Example code that causes failure:

```
@functions_framework.http
def hello_get(request):
    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    ...
    # Get prediction using Vertex AI endpoint
    instance = get_prediction(request_json['instances'])
    "Example output is a list of 512 float values"

    output = zip(request_json['instances'], instance)
    sorted_output = sorted(output, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    f_output = dict(sorted_output)
    return f_output
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me, I was hoping someone could help.

My environment is:

```
functions-framework==3.2.0
flask==2.1.0
google-cloud-error-reporting==1.6.0
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.16.1
1st Gen Cloud Function, 1gb, unauthenticated access, trigger HTTP
```

OR even more oddly this works as well:

```
@functions_framework.http
def hello_get(request):
    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    ...
    # Get prediction using Vertex AI endpoint
    instance = get_prediction(request_json['instances'])
    "Example output is a list of 512 float values"

    output = zip(request_json['instances'], instance)
    sorted_output = sorted(output, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    f_output = dict(sorted_output)
    # wrapping dict in str
    return str(f_output)
```

This returns the desired output dictionary {'fox':[0.002,...]}, but as a string.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a minimally reproducible example of your code rather than mostly the error. Please don't include screenshots in questions as these may not outlive the question.

Comment: Your code snippet suggests that the object is a `dict` but the error message suggests that it's actually a `RepeatedComposite`. Google's libraries often return protobuf objects. In Python, often using [Proto Plus](https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io). If that's true in this case, then you should (!?) be able to convert the object to JSON with the [`to_json`](https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages.html?highlight=JSON#serialization) function on the returned class (!) with the object as a parameter. It's unclear what the returned type is without a better code snippet.

Comment: Hey @DazWilkin I fixed it to have a minimal example, I just tried wrapping the dictionary in a string and it seems to work for some reason. Only problem is I don't want the return in a string!

Comment: It seems similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860448/object-of-type-repeatedcompositecontainer-is-not-json-serializable