# Python Flask request.data returning string only

Tags: python, flask, postman

I just starting working with Python and Flask. I created a basic rest and I won't to get data that I send using Postman.
Data:

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "12345"
}
```

My python code

```
from flask import Flask, request
...

@app.route("/Test", methods=['POST'])
   def Test():
      print(request.data)
...
```

I can see in the terminal that it prints `b'{\n\t"username": "test",\n\t"password": "12345"\n}'` 
How can I get the values? I'm looking for something like:

```
request.data.username
request.data.password
```

How can I do it using python?

BTW, I tried to to request.json and it returned 'none'. Also, request.form returned 'ImmutableMultiDict([])'.

Thanks

Comment: `json.loads(request.data)` ?

Comment: it seems you would have to use `application/json` in Postman and then you get it in  `request.json` (instead of `None`). https://stackoverflow.com/a/20001283/1832058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.json), one alternative for you is to use `get_json`

> get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)

So you can try:

```py
print(request.get_json()) # you can use force=True to force a parsing as json.

## access values:

rjson = request.get_json()

username = rjson['username']
psswd = rjson['password']
```

To really make sure the json is send and read correctly, use the `MIME`: `application/json`.

[image]