# How to send JSON from HTML link to Python Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, post, flask

I have a certain JSON object already setted in my HTML code, which via Jinja2 I receive and proceed to perform actions with.

```
let selectedJson = {{json | safe}}
```

This is the way I send it in the first place:

```
@app.route('/pad/analizador222/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def analizador222():
        littleJSON = {"something" : "something-else"}
        mode = 1
        return render_template("output.html", json = littleJSON , mode = mode )
```

Now, after I did some stuff with the object, I need to re-send it back to another "@app.route()" via an HTML LINK, for example:

```
<a>This is the link I need to click on to send the previously mentioned JSON</a>
```

Here's the other app.route()

```
@app.route('/analisis-conversaciones', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def analisisconversaciones():
        return render_template("analysis.html")
```

I need to do some other stuff that does not matter at the moment with that JSON in "analysis.html"

The question is:

> How can I send that JSON object via a common HTML link?

I think POST protocol can help, but in that case I don't know how to use it.

Comment: maybe this is what you looking for [send json in post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614301/11225821)