# how to test flask api in pycharm

Tags: python, flask

I have create a Flask Api (simple demo)

It will take a json and add those values and return addition.

Can anyone tell me how can i call that API with param?

please help me  with this.

I have attached what I have done.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    data = request.get_json()
    return jsonify({'sum': data['x'] + data['x']})

app.run(port=5003)
```

when i used below code it gives an error `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

I used this code from diff .py file

```
url='http://127.0.0.1:5003/'
response = app.test_client().post(
        '/add',
        data=json.dumps({'x': 1, 'y': 2}),
        content_type='application/json',
    )
```

I want to call that API from diff .py file, this is what i want.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about the error, but `app.test_client().post(url+'/add' ...)` in `diff.py` seems wrong. You already have a trailing slash in the `url` string variable. So maybe you want to do `url + 'add'` instead?

Comment: @JakeTae by mistake!, updated

Comment: It looks like you are running another application on port `5003`. You need to stop that application first and then run the flask app

Comment: @SirajusSalekin , if i stop it, then how can i call that API and check whether it is  running or not

Comment: you are trying to run it twice somewhere in your code

Comment: @SirajusSalekin I got sol here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask