# post json data in jinja-flask framework

Tags: python, json, flask, post, jinja2

Am new to flask+jinja2 and am trying to post json data to my server from jinja2 template and store the json data in db.

However when I use the following code in my jinja2 html and post, I cant seem to read it as json data and flask is reading it as string and truncating the data. please help.

myhtml.html:

```
<form action= "/v1/json_data" method="post">
    <!-- some code -->
    {% set json_data =  process_data()  %}
    <input type="hidden" name="json_data" value={{ json_data|safe }}>
    <input type="submit" name="form_data" value="Submit">
</form>
```

views.py:

```
@app.route('/v1/json_data', methods=['POST'])
def read_json_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = request.form["some_id_i_defined_in_html"]
        json_data = request.form.get('json_data', None)
        print(form_data) # works as expected :)
        print(json_data) # only prints first key as string :(
        return json_data
```

My json_data is of the following format:

```
{"level1a": {"level2a": "2a", "level2aa": "2aa"},
"level1b": {"level2b": "2b", "level2bb": "2bb"}}
```

The json_data print statement in views.py only prints

> {"level1a":

and I expect entire json structure. What am I missing here? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `flask.request.json` to return a JSON object decoded from the request. This question is similar to: [How to get POSTed JSON in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask)

```
    json_data = flask.request.json
    a_value = json_data["a_key"]
```