# How to connect Rasa with Flask

Tags: python, flask, rasa

First I have enabled the API by using

```
rasa run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug
```

then I tested that using postman;
it's showing the intent ranking:

[image: Screen shot of Postman]

In the next step want to run web, so I have the written a Flask app.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

#@app.route('/')
#def hello_world():
    #return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/chat',methods=["POST"])
def chat():

        user_message = request.form['text']
        response = requests.post("http://localhost:5005/model/parse", params ={"message": user_message} )
        return jsonify({"status":"success","response":response_text})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)
```

but I'm unable to fetch the intent ranking over there.
This the output while I'm using flask app:

[image: Flask screenshot]

Can someone help me sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Your flask endpoint is expecting input from the **form**. You are sending a POST request with JSON in your second Postman example.

You have two options (do only one of them, doing both will get you the same error):

A) change your postman request, so it uses form-data instead of JSON. This has worked for me:[image: Postman screenshot]

B) Rewrite processing of the request in your code. You are sending JSON in your POST request, so you should process JSON, see [How to get POSTed JSON in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/chat',methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    user_message = request.get_json()['text']
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:5005/model/parse", params={"message": user_message} )
    return jsonify({"status": "success", "response": response.text})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)
```

Comment: Can you the please elaborate, i didnt get you