# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str (flask app)

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, flask

Hello i'm facing the following error message saying "**TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str**". I'm not sure why this is the case, this is my API requests below:

```
import requests

apiKey = "MyAPIkey"
jsonValues = {
    "X-Api-Key" : apiKey,
    "start_date" : "2021-01-01",
    "end_date" : "2021-04-01",
    "company_idx" : [1,2]
}

headers = {'x-api-key': apiKey,
           'content-type': 'application/json'}

companyLastScore = requests.post("https://app/api_endpoint", headers=headers, json=jsonValues).json()
```

In the backend, my app has the following code:

```
@app.route('/api_endpoint', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def api_companiesScore():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    auth = request_data['X-Api-Key']

    if request_data:
        if 'company_idx' in request_data:
            if (type(request_data['company_idx']) == list) and (len(request_data['company_idx']) > 0):
                company_ids_list = [int(x) for x in request_data['company_idx']]
                
                start_date = request_data['start_date']
                end_date = request_data['end_date']
                    
                connectionInstance, cursorInstance = connectToDB()
                result = get_table2_companies(connectionInstance, company_ids_list, start_date, end_date)
                return result
        
            else:
                return jsonify({"message": "ERROR: Unauthorized"}), 401
```

Would you know what's wrong?

The error message from google app engine is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 2757, in api_companiesScore
    auth = request_data['X-Api-Key']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: The traceback indicates that `request_data` is a tuple so it can only use index like `requests_data[0]`, but `request.get_json()` should return a dict instead of tuple, weird.

Comment: I think it depends on your version of Flask. Try ```request_data = request.json``` instead (see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614301/15211203)

Comment: still doesn't work