# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' in request_json

Tags: python, json, docker, curl, containers

I have a Python application :

**main.py**

```
import os
import logging
import datetime
import functools
import jwt

# pylint: disable=import-error
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort

"""
A simple app to create a JWT token.
"""

JWT_SECRET = os.environ.get('JWT_SECRET', 'myjwtsecret')
LOG_LEVEL = os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG')

def _logger():
    '''
    Setup logger format, level, and handler.
    RETURNS: log object
    '''
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    log.addHandler(stream_handler)
    return log


LOG = _logger()
LOG.debug("Starting with log level: %s" % LOG_LEVEL )
APP = Flask(__name__)

def require_jwt(function):
    """
    Decorator to check valid jwt is present.
    """
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kws):
        if not 'Authorization' in request.headers:
            abort(401)
        data = request.headers['Authorization']
        token = str.replace(str(data), 'Bearer ', '')
        try:
            jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=['HS256'])
        except: # pylint: disable=bare-except
            abort(401)

        return function(*args, **kws)
    return decorated_function


@APP.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def health():
    return jsonify("Healthy")


@APP.route('/auth', methods=['POST'])
def auth():
    """
    Create JWT token based on email.
    """
    request_data = request.get_json()
    if request_data is None:
        print("request returned None")
    else:
        print("doing somethings")
    email = request_data.get('email')
    password = request_data.get('password')
    if not email:
        LOG.error("No email provided")
        return jsonify({"message": "Missing parameter: email"}, 400)
    if not password:
        LOG.error("No password provided")
        return jsonify({"message": "Missing parameter: password"}, 400)
    body = {'email': email, 'password': password}

    user_data = body

    #return jsonify(token=_get_jwt(user_data).decode('utf-8'))
    return jsonify(token=_get_jwt(user_data))
    


@APP.route('/contents', methods=['GET'])
def decode_jwt():
    """
    Check user token and return non-secret data
    """
    if not 'Authorization' in request.headers:
        abort(401)
    data = request.headers['Authorization']
    token = str.replace(str(data), 'Bearer ', '')
    try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=['HS256'])
    except: # pylint: disable=bare-except
        abort(401)


    response = {'email': data['email'],
                'exp': data['exp'],
                'nbf': data['nbf'] }
    return jsonify(**response)


def _get_jwt(user_data):
    exp_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=2)
    payload = {'exp': exp_time,
               'nbf': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
               'email': user_data['email']}
    return jwt.encode(payload, JWT_SECRET, algorithm='HS256')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

executed under a Docker container:

The Docker image is created with:

```
docker build --tag jwt-api-test .
```

and executed with:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 --env-file=.env_file jwt-api-test
```

**.env_file:**

```
JWT_SECRET='myjwtsecret'
LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

So when I test with Postman:

> localhost:80/auth

With Body:

```
{
"Email": "test@test.com",
"Password": "pass"
}
```

and Header :

```
application/json
```

it returns to me the error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

And in the terminal window, or it was executed the Docker container, I can read:

```
  File "/app/main.py", line 84, in auth
    email = request_data.get('email')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

And when I test in a second terminal the following CURL command:

```
export TOKEN=`curl --data '{"email":"test@test.com","password":"pass"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:80/auth  | jq -r '.token'`
```

I receive the error:

> Connection refused

I do not know if it's a python code error or it's a different IP from the Docker container or anothing error ?

I need your help please.

Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you add your dockerfile and steps you used to get the container up and map ports since you are running on port 80

Comment: I think you aren't getting anything in `request_data` so that error occur.

Comment: with postman, I'd suggest checking if you have set content type as `application/json` else `get_json()` will return `None`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20001283/5236575

Comment: See documentation on [`request.get_json`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json). Make sure you're setting the write `Content-Type` header in your request from Postman

Comment: whenever you run a `request` its best to add a None check. 

`if request_data is None:
    print("request returned None")
else:    print("doing somethings")`

Comment: even the **docker-macine ls** command, for searching the container's IP, does not return any active manchine. Curl now return : **parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10** !?