# How to insert data into my database with php without form?

Tags: javascript, php, database, insert

Please help me, I have a game on my website, but I don't know how to insert that poin into my database because I do not use a form.

I also want to ask, how to enter data without using form into the global variable `$_POST`? (You can use PHP or javascript for it)

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>
    Your point :
    <span class="poin">120</span> <!-- It will be inserted into the database -->
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not well-versed in PHP, but you'll want to take a look at AJAX. I wrote an answer for a similar problem using flask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74230109/13376511) (note: that answer uses Python, not PHP, so you'll need to do some translating)

Comment: at least you should think how should the system trigger an insert (or update) of the data ? (on change of the value by some means ? on click of a button ? etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Without a form, you can send a `POST` request to your server by using the fetch API.

Just add the following JavaScript code:

```
const poin = document.querySelector('.container .point').textContent
;(async () => {
  await fetch('host:port', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ point })
  })
})()
```

And replace `'host:port'` to the correct host and port (of your server).

With `document.querySelector('.container .point')` you are selecting the DOM-element which CSS-selector is `'.point'`.
`fetch` accepts the following parameters: `url` and `[options]`. The `[options]` (which is optional) is a object with the following properties: `method`, `headers` and `body`, among others.

Comment: I am sorry, my server was forbidden. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a CORS-related problem?