# How do I set the content-type for POST requests in python-requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

One API I'm currently using specifies that I need a special content-type string. I don't know how do I set this in python-requests library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: Just set the header? `requests` will set the `Content-Type` only if you use `data`, `files` or `json` as arguments to the `requests.post()` call, and you can always override that with the `headers` dictionary.

Answer (score 114):

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-type': 'content_type_value'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: For anyone else who ended up here because of googling an error message: Note that usually, you don't want to explicitely set the header. The requests library will do it for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57479286/4629950 . The answer from Vikas Ohja is still correct because in this case the question was explicitely about setting it manually.

Comment: Note that there are [some specific situations](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) in which the `requests` library does not set the `Content-Type` header for you.