# How should I pass text/plain data to python's requests.post?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I am trying to convert this `curl` command in python requests, but I am unsure about how I should pass the data:

```bash
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
    --header "Content-Type: text/plain" \
    --data "some plain text data" \
    "{url}"
```

I have tried to pass the string directly and to encode it with `str.encode('utf-8')` but I get an error 415 `Unsupported Media Type`

This is my code:

```py
text = "some random text"
resp = requests.post(url, data=text, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, auth=('apikey', self.apikey))
```

Comment: Normally,  `import requests
    text = "some random text"
    resp = requests.requests("POST",url, data=text.encode('utf-8'), headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, auth=('apikey', self.apikey))` should work. But this could often depend on the target . If you give the target to which you are posting this data, maybe we could try directly with that

Comment: do not set `headers` like `Content-Type` in `requests` manually

Comment: Thanks @IvanVinogradov, this worked like a charm although I'm still surprised that setting the headers does not work

Comment: @IvanVinogradov, can you post this as an answer? (preferably with a short explanation, but any answer is better than none at all)

Comment: Sure, I’ll make a post

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using `requests` library, it is usually a good idea **not** to set `Content-Type` header manually using `headers=` keyword.

> If you need [the Content-Type header] set and you don't want to encode the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly using the `json` parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically:
>
> ```
> r = requests.post(url, json={'some': 'data'})
> ```
>
> Note, the `json` parameter is ignored if either `data` or `files` is passed.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Another reason for not setting this type of header manually is **encoding**, because sometimes you should specify something like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

One more important thing about `Content-Type` is that this header is not required for making POST requests. [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
> Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If
> and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
> recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
> content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
> resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
> treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

So depending on the server type you're making request to, this header may be left empty.

---

Sorry for this explanation being a bit vague. I cannot give you an exact explanation why this approach worked for you unless you provide target URL.

Comment: The `Content-Type` header will not be set automatically if you give `str` or `bytes` data to the `data` parameter.