# How to pass plain text(string) in post request using locust?

Tags: python, api, testing, token, locust

Hi I need to pass plain text (string) in payload if I pass it in json format it won't work so I need to pass it in string only. I am using locust framework can anyone tell me know I can pass simple string in payload?

from locust import task, SequentialTaskSet, HttpUser, constant
import json

```
class LL(SequentialTaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        res2 = self.client.post("url", name="name",
                            headers={"Accept": "*/*", 
                            "Content-Type": "text/plain"},
                            data=("bb=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        print('token ', res2.status_code)


@task
def printing(self):
    print('PPP')

class BL(HttpUser): 
    wait_time = constant(5) 
    host = "*****" 
    tasks = [LL]
```

Please help me out thanks in advance.

I have already added "Content-Type": "text/plain" and also tried with json dumps but getting 404 to get a 200 status I need to pass the payload as a string only. I have checked in postman and thunderhead client it is working fine there only if we pass payload as a string.
I have also tried it by adding user agent but not working.

Comment: Just need to add one point the string I am pasing is encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Locust's client [inherits from the Python Requests library](https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#control-headers-or-other-things-about-my-http-requests). The majority of the time, for questions like this you should be able to find applicable answers by looking for the same thing for Requests.

In this case, try removing your headers.

[How should I pass text/plain data to python's requests.post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458203/how-should-i-pass-text-plain-data-to-pythons-requests-post)

Comment: Good answer. Another tip is to log the actual request, as documented here: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-in-debugger.html#print-http-communication

Comment: still not working after removing headers if I use requests library it is working fine. I am able to send string in payload but I need to use locust and that is giving 404 on passing string in payload.

Comment: Then follow @cyberwiz suggestion and print out your request to compare Locust is sending.