# translate curl query to requests

Tags: python, curl

I was trying to get hand on using documentation at:
https://pairbulkdata.uspto.gov/#/api-documentation

However when I tried those query, I got error message.
I am trying to translate curl query to python requests.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"searchText":"medicine AND diabetes","qf": "patentTitle"}' http://pairbulkdata.uspto.gov/queries
```

Here is the python code that I am trying:

```
import requests

data = {"searchText":"medicine AND diabetes","qf": "patentTitle"}

url = "http://pairbulkdata.uspto.gov/queries"

header = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

r = requests.post(url, data = data, headers=header)
```

But I get error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">\n<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>ERROR</H1>\n<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>\n<HR noshade size="1px">\nBad request.\n<BR clear="all">\n<HR noshade size="1px">\n<PRE>\nGenerated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\nRequest ID: OIhwX7a3zVJq04M_qf0sjWhuke3fHb1-6wFJsN7UX_Rp2w_gzebTGA==\n</PRE>\n<ADDRESS>\n</ADDRESS>\n</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: When I run that `curl` command, I get the exact same output. So, try fixing your request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: maybe they are problem in server.

Comment: in your documentation is example - link to page which display result of query (before `Case 2`) It use `API` to get data so you can use `DevTools` in Chrome/Frirefox to see request. They even can create `curl` code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converters which can convert `curl` into `requests`

http://curl.trillworks.com/

https://shibukawa.github.io/curl_as_dsl/index.html

---

**EDIT:**

I checked documentation and there is link to page which uses API to get data

https://pairbulkdata.uspto.gov/#/search?q=medicine%20AND%20diabetes&sort=applId%20asc

It seems it uses url with `/api/queries` but documentations shows `/queries`

-

This code gives me some data as JSON - so probably it works

```
curl 'https://pairbulkdata.uspto.gov/api/queries' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"searchText":"medicine AND diabetes","qf": "patentTitle"}'
```

-

And this gives some results too.

```
import requests

url = "https://pairbulkdata.uspto.gov/api/queries"

headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

data = {"searchText":"medicine AND diabetes","qf": "patentTitle"}

r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

I use

- `https://` instead of `http://`
- `/api/queries` instead of `/queries`
- `json=` instead of `data=`