# How to send python nested dictionary with requests library to PHP script?

Tags: php, python, json, python-requests

I have a simple t1.php file which has:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

and a simple python file  which has:

```
import requests
print requests.post("http://localhost/tempo/t1.php", data={"a":{"b": "c", "d": "e"}}).text
```

and when I run the python file I get:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

The question is, where are other parameters and values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: I am not getting 400, and also when I do json= instead of data=, the output would be nothing and even worse

Comment: you can try first `json_encode($_POST)` than see what will be output

Comment: yeah actually I realized that data= encodes the data into parameters format in the body, but with json= it will put the whole thing into the body of the post message which is the true way of doing that, but it is not accessible with $_POST[] and you have to do file_get_contents('php://input') to get your json data.