# How to send photo bytes as JPEG image in text/json request using python

Tags: python, json, api, jpeg

I think that I'm working with a bad API design here, according to the documentation I need to send photo bytes as JPEG in the request, my question is: How to send this bytes in a text/json? below is the documentation to sending photos to this API.

[Documentation of sending photos to API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oli0Z.png)

Below is my put request in python:

```
reply = requests.put(url, data=blob, headers=self.headers)
```

where blob is the binary of the image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests

Comment: Hi Benjamin. I know how to send text in the requests my doubt is about the blob/binary in request of type text/json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, just encode blob to base64 before and then use the json.dumps.

```
blob = json.dumps(blob.encode("base64"))
reply = requests.put(url, json=blob, headers=self.headers)
```