# Google Webmaster API gives Response 500: Backend Error on every request

Tags: python, api, google-search-console

I'm calling the google API myself instead of using their python Library because I'm behind an inconvenient corporate proxy which kills their library, so I have to do it all myself.

This works fine:

```
requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites', params = 
{'access_token':'my_access_token_here'})
```

This on the other hand, doesn't:

```
site = https://www.my_website_from_the_above_function.com
site = urllib.parse.quote_plus(site)


def get_website_info():
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/{}/searchAnalytics/query'.format(site)
    params = { 
    "endDate": "2017-12-10",
    "startDate": "2017-12-01",
    "access_token": my_access_token
    }

    r = requests.post(url, params = params)

    return r


x = get_website_info().json()
```

All I get is this error code:

```
{'error': {'code': 500,
  'errors': [{'domain': 'global',
    'message': 'Backend Error',
    'reason': 'backendError'}],
  'message': 'Backend Error'}}
```

Even with the reccomended 'Exponential backoff'
Using [googles API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/searchanalytics/m/webmasters/v3/webmasters.searchanalytics.query?) seems to work fine:

[image: Google screenshot]

Aditionally: This also seems give similar errors:

```
r = requests.post(url, params = auth_params, data = json.dumps(params))
```

and finally:

```
r = requests.post(url, params = auth_params, data = params)
```

just gives

```
{'error': {'code': 400,
  'errors': [{'domain': 'global',
    'message': 'This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.',
    'reason': 'parseError'}],
  'message': 'This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.'}}
```

Comment: For your `500` error... no idea, really... For the second one, it looks like (maybe) you have to have to specify that the `Content-Type` request's header is `Application/Json`? Check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9733638/289011

Comment: Got it you set me on the right track! I had to pass in, 
  `headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % access_token}`

and json.dumps(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can think of the contents of a `request` as just text, right? Not only text, but text that accepts a relatively limited number of characters.

With that in mind, it all boils down on how to serialize "complex" data structures into text. I recently answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48013744/289011) about files that is *kinddddaaa* similar idea.

If you have a bunch of `key=value` parameters, you could use a simple "trick":

> 1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by
>      `+`, and then reserved characters are escaped as described in
>      [[RFC1738]](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by
>      `%HH`, a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the
>      ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as `"CR LF"`
>      pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A`).
> 2. The control names/values are listed in the
>      order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the
>      value by `=` and name/value pairs are separated from each other by
>      `&`.

So this data:

```
{a="foo", b="bar baz"}
```

Could be serialized into text following the specification above like: `a=foo&b=bar+baz`

That serialization format is identified as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the `Content-type` request's header. That request's header is telling the server that receives it something like *"Hey! The data that is coming in my `body` is serialized following that convention that separates keys from values using the `=` symbol and splits key/value pairs using &, changes whitespaces by `+`... and so on"*

**(!) Very important:** That is the format used by the `requests` module on a `POST` unless told otherwise.

Another format, which allows more flexibility (such as maintaining basic types or nesting structures) is [JSON](https://www.json.org/). That is the format that the Google server "wants", and in order to tell servers that the "text" contained in the request's body follows the Json standard (or convention), the `Content-Type` header must be set to `'application/json'`.

What appears that your Google server was doing upon receiving a `request` was checking the `Content-type` header and if it wasn't Json, it gave you a [`400`](https://httpstatuses.com/400) error to indicate "*Oh, I don't understand this format... I want Json!*"

That's why you have to specify the Json header.

There's an example comparing both formats [here](https://www.smtpeter.com/en/documentation/json-vs-post).

You can also see it more clearly since the latest versions of `requests` module can do the JSON parsing for you. Since the JSON format has become so common, you can pass data provided in a Python structure (a `dict`, for instance) through the [`json=`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) argument, and the module will do the `json.dumps` and set the header for you. This also allows you to "introspect" a little how the body will look like (to see the differences maybe more clearly).

Check this out:

```
from requests import Request

data = {
    'a': 'foo-1 baz',
    'b': 5,
    'c': [1, 2, 3],
    'd': '6'
}

req = Request('POST', 'http://foo.bar', data=data)
prepped = req.prepare()
print("Normal headers: %s" % prepped.headers)
print("Normal body: %s" % prepped.body)

req = Request('POST', 'http://foo.bar', json=data)
prepped = req.prepare()
print("Json headers: %s" % prepped.headers)
print("Json body: %s" % prepped.body)
```

Outputs:

```
Normal headers: {'Content-Length': '31', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
Normal body: d=6&a=foo-1+baz&c=1&c=2&c=3&b=5
Json headers: {'Content-Length': '52', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
Json body: b'{"d": "6", "a": "foo-1 baz", "c": [1, 2, 3], "b": 5}'
```

See the difference? JSON is capable of making a difference between the strings `foo-1` or `6` (using `"`) as opposed to `5` being an integer, while the `x-www-form` can't (see how the form encoding doesn't differentiate between the *integer* 5 or the *string* 6). Same with the list. By using the character `[`, the server will be able to tell that `c` is a list (and of integers)

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The solution:

was to pass in header information with:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % access_token}
```

and make sure the json data was dumped to a string:

```
r = requests.post(url,data = json.dumps(params),  headers = headers)
```

If someone could explain the reason behind my answer, that would be great.

Comment: You can think of the contents of your request as "text", right? There's no much magic that can be done: it is just text. Then the `Content-type` header tells the server *how* the text is formatted. By default, the `requests` module tells the server that is formatted as a `form`, and it (the server) doesn't like that: it wants JSON, but the header says it's formatted as a `form`. The server doesn't look any further and rejects it. There's a bit more info here: https://www.smtpeter.com/en/documentation/json-vs-post

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, if you were to write up an answer, I'd be more than happy to mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: Well, that is very kind of you. I did it **:-)** I hope the explanation is clear. Dunno, maybe not (maybe it's too long, and beating around the bush) If you have more questions about this, add a comment so it pops out in my S.O. *inbox* and I'll try to answer (to the extent of my possibilities, which are not... are not that many) **:-/**