# Pass Input through API Gateway to Lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to pass a JSON object like `{'inputNum': 8}` from a python script on my local machine through a request and have the body return with whether the number is even or odd. I have a simple lambda function that checks this and it works with my test cases, but I do not know how to configure API Gateway to accept input from a request. This is my current code to request the API

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    method = 'GET'
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    body = {'inputNum': '8'}
    url = "****.amazon/prod/testEven"
    response = requests.request(method, url, data=body, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

but it gives me `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the API Gateway on the Integration Request do you have 'Use Lambda Proxy integration' checked?

Comment: yes, I also have it linked up to my lambda function

Comment: Did you create a deployment to prod stage? Did you test the API gateway itself?

Comment: I deployed it to prod, but have not been able to get the API gateway work. When I enter a test query string for prod I get {"message": "Internal server error"}

Comment: Is your requests.request really sending JSON?  There's either some magical behavior here, or it isn't doing what you think.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315/1695906

Comment: Is the request invoking the lambda or is it failing in the api gateway?