# The output of OrderedDict has single quotes around it, and I want just the insides without single quotes

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x, python-requests

So I was trying to use OrderedDict inside json.dumps() and it started off working well. However, when trying to use the output directly inside a payload of an HTTP PUT request, it has these single quotes around it that I believe is screwing with the way the json is being interpreted at the receiving end.

So how do I get around this and have it give me the output without the single quotes?

Example:

```
out = json.dumps(OrderedDict([("name", 1), ("value", 2)]))
```

... gives an output such as:

```
'{"name": 1, "value": 2}'
```

... when I want it to give me the meat, the json, like:

```
{"name": 1, "value": 2}
```

... so that I can put that straight into my

`r = requests.post(url, data = out)`

... and be on my merry way.

As an aside: is there something VERY basic about strings and string literals (whatever those are) that I am completely missing? My Python knowledge being self taught I am sure there are some gaps.

EDIT:
`print(out)`

... gives

`{"name": 1, "value": 2}`

which is what I believe I want.

EDIT2: `json = out` as mentioned in the selected answer did the trick thank you! However, since I am just starting out with coding in Python, I would love to know whether you have come across any articles/ documentation that might be handy for me to know so as to avoid similar issues in the future. Thanks once again everyone!

Comment: Yeah! I mean the response is bad and everything else has been checked. So it has got to be this.

Comment: The obvious thing you are missing is that [json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) returns a string. The `'{"name": 1, "value": 2}'` is how strings are displayed when inspected - the `'` are just delimiters that are NOT part of the string - the error mus be elsewhere.

Comment: Tried that and it gave me `'{"value": 2, "name": 1}'`
Last time I tried using extra brackets, it gave me `'{"name": 1, "value": 2}'` so essentially all it gives me is an unordered json dict.

Comment: Also, if json.dumps() outputs a string, then isn't that not entirely useful? Or is the receiving end json able to read it as json since it has the curly brackets and colons and such?

Comment: ... that is the whole point of JSON - you transfer data as string in a kinda stringent format so it can be parsed on the other end ...

Comment: Tried the way you said it and this is the error: `invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: Worth noting: the JSON interchange format does not provide any ordering guarantees on key/value pairs. If the order of keys is important, you will need to serialize into JSON using a list of objects rather than just a single object.

Comment: I wonder if part of your problem might be because the POST body is a bytestream, but you're passing a `str` object (a Unicode string) rather than a `bytes` object (a bytestring). Since you're also not passing any `Content-Type` header, I'm not sure how `requests` will serialize the request for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` will encode the data for you. You should be able to pass the `OrderedDict` directly to `post`:

```
out = OrderedDict([("name", 1), ("value", 2)])
r = requests.post(url, json=out)
```

I hope this helps.

---

EDIT: I realized there's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315/6118299) that may help you and it suggests using `json` instead of `data` when making the `post` call.

Documentation:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Thank you! I am not 100% sure how (I will make sure to read up about this) but `json = out` did the trick! Maybe it was about being explicit which is something I know Python likes.