# I need help converting this REST API Curl command to Python requests

Tags: python, rest, curl, python-requests, rt

I'm new around here, and rather new to all that is coding to be honest.

I'm trying to create a Pyton script to search for items from a Request Tracker asset database using REST API.

So far I got this Curl command:

```
curl    -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '[{ "field" : "Owner", "operator" : "LIKE", "value" : "NAME" },{"field":"Catalog", "value":"1"}]' \
-H 'Authorization: token MY_TOKEN' \
'https://RT_URL/rt/REST/2.0/assets'
```

It returns a nice JSON with results from RT_URL where Owner is matching NAME using token MY_TOKEN.

But I don't know how to code this in Python. I have a script that use the requests library to fetch is using a simple URL request, but I can't figure out how to implement the search fields.

I've looked all over to find a sample, but I can't get it to work. I haven't found any info on how to authenticate in requests using a token.

Anyway, thanks in advance for any respons :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'token TOKEN',
}

data = '[{ "field" : "value"}] ......'

response = requests.post('YOUR_URL', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `requests.post()` to perform a HTTP POST request to your REST API:

```
import requests
import json

# URL
url = 'https://RT_URL/rt/REST/2.0/assets'

# JSON data 
data = '[{ "field" : "Owner", "operator" : "LIKE", "value" : "NAME" },{"field":"Catalog", "value":"1"}]'

# Request headers
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "token MY_TOKEN"}

# POST request
requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's build headers dict for your request:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', (...)
}
```

then, let's create your body:

```
json = [{
        "field": "Owner",
        "operator": "LIKE",
        "value": "NAME"
    }, {
        "field": "Catalog",
        "value": "1"
    }]
```

Finally, let's POST your request:

```
response = requests.post('https://RT_URL/rt/REST/2.0/assets', json=json, headers=headers)
```

This should do the trick.

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315/5337455)