# Sending JSON with array of dicts with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send json containing array of dicts with requests module.
Here's sample of my code:

```
payload = {
    "arrayData": [
        {
            "key1": 1,
            "key2": 2,
            "key3": {
                "subkey": 3
            }
        }
    ]
}
r = requests.post(
    'https://httpbin.org/post',
    data = payload,
)
print(r.text)
```

Here's what I believe my request looks like:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "arrayData": [
      "key1", 
      "key2", 
      "key3"
    ]
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "44", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

The problem is arrayData at some moment turns to plain list of values.

It is crucial to my task to send that json as form but I'm out of ideas how to do that. Sending request with json=payload or with data=json.dumps(payload) doesn't do the trick because parsed data goes to "json" part but I need it in "form".

In my example arrayData contains only one dict, but there may be several.

Comment: Did you mean to send it as form data? Perhaps you may want to send JSON instead: `data=json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that, it parses correctly but goes to "json" part and "form" becomes empty.

Comment: @Rodriger what exactly is the API you're using expecting?

Comment: It expects form with arrayData field that contains array of JSON dicts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: @Rodriger that doesn't really make any sense though...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was form with arrayData field and JSON content, so correct payload  should be like this:

```
payload = {
"arrayData": json.dumps([{
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": {
        "subkey": 3
        }
    }])
}
```