# Posting data on Airtable API does not work

Tags: python-3.x, post, airtable

I am trying to  create a new table on Airtable with the aid of the *post* method. I have the following code :

```
# importing the requests library 
import requests 

# defining the api-endpoint 
API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appa3r2UUo4JxpjSv/Table%201?api_key=MYKEY"


# data to be sent to api 
data =  {
   'fields': {
        'Name': 'Andromachis Row'
    } 

} 

# sending post request and saving response as response object 
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)

# extracting response text 
print(r.text)
```

Despite that  when I run the script I get an error saying:

```
(mypyth) PS C:\Users\andri\PythonProjects\mypyth> py post_API.py
{"error":{"type":"INVALID_REQUEST_UNKNOWN","message":"Invalid request: parameter validation failed. Check your request data."}}
```

Does anyone understand why this happens? I am really desperate! Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `json=data` instead of `data=data`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests

Comment: Any update on this? I am experiencing the same.