# How to read data from csv file and parse to python POST requests as a dict format

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to read data from a CSV file and parse that into Python POST requests in a dictionary format which will create a content-type: `multipart/form-data auto` when sending a request to the API.

I have tried

```py
with open("listingData1.csv", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        data_android = {

        'mailing_details': row["shipping"],
        'caroupay':'false',
        'price':row['price'],
        'description':row['desc'],
        'title':row['title'],
        'meetup':'false',
        'condition':'2',
        'mailing':'true',
        'collection_id':row['cat']
        }
        print(row)
        search_path = row['image']
        urls = []
        for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+search_path):
            if file.endswith((".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".JPG",".JPEG",".PNG")):
                x = os.getcwd()+"\\"+search_path+"\\"+file
                urls.append(x)


        files = {'photo_%s' % x: ('photo_%s.jpg' % x, open(file, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg') for x, file in enumerate(urls)}
        #print data_android
        response = requests.request("POST", url_and,data=data_android,headers=headers)
        print(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

However, requests send data to the API with `content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is not accepted by the API:

```
'POST /api/3.0/listings/ HTTP/1.1\r
Host: api.testdomain.com\r
Connection: keep-alive\r
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r
Accept: */*\r
User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0\r
platform: android\r
Authorization: Token afs7dfa76sd8f7a68sd76f8as6fd8s\r
Content-Length: 179\r
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r
\r
abcpay=FALSE&description=test1&mailing_details=FREE&price=239.00&title=Pet+Cat+Dog+Carrier+Portable+Breathable+Comfortable&meetup=FALSE&collection_id=45&mailing=TRUE&condition=2'
```

After that, I tried to use the default dictreader option from CSV module:

```
with open("listingData1.csv", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        search_path = row['image']
        urls = []
        for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+search_path):
            if file.endswith((".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".JPG",".JPEG",".PNG")):
                x = os.getcwd()+"\\"+search_path+"\\"+file
                urls.append(x)


        files = {'photo_%s' % x: ('photo_%s.jpg' % x, open(file, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg') for x, file in enumerate(urls)}
        #print data_android
        response = requests.request("POST", url_and,data=row,headers=headers)
        print(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

which also gives the same output. Now, is there any way to parse CSV data into POST requests as a dictionary file?

Here is my full code:

```
import requests
import logging
import os
import json
import csv

try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

url_and = "https://api.test.com/api/3.0/listings/"

android_token = '8fas8d7f9a8s7d9f87as9d8f7sa9df7s9f'
headers = {
    'Authorization': "Token " + android_token,
    'platform': 'android',
}

data_android = {}

with open("listingData1.csv", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        data_android = {
        'mailing_details':row['shipping'],
        'abcoupay':'false',
        'price':row['price'],
        'description':row['desc'],
        'title':row['title'],
        'meetup':'false',
        'condition':'2',
        'mailing':'true',
        'collection_id':row['cat']
        }

        search_path = row['image']
        urls = []
        for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+search_path):
            if file.endswith((".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".JPG",".JPEG",".PNG")):
                x = os.getcwd()+"\\"+search_path+"\\"+file
                urls.append(x)


        files = {'photo_%s' % x: ('photo_%s.jpg' % x, open(file, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg') for x, file in enumerate(urls)}

        response = requests.request("POST", url_and,data=data_android,headers=headers)
        print(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)