# Sending metadata along with a dataframe using Requests POST request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm using pythons Requests to send a Pandas Dataframe to a Flask server. The dataframe has about 2 million rows and 16 columns. I want to send a config dictionary along with the dataframe, as metadata. At the moment I am able to send the dataframe as a JSON file, however, I can't find any way to attach the metadata in the same post request.

Here's my code:

**Client side:**

```
 # Post request containing 1. The dataset (pandas df) 2. The metadata (dict)

 dataset = dataset.to_json(orient='split')
 metadata = {'dataset ID': "makis", 'date start': "1", 'date end': "2"}

 url = "http://localhost:8081/upload_dataset"
 r = requests.post(url, data=dataset)
 return r.text
```

**Server side:**

```
@app.route("/upload_dataset", methods=['POST'])

def upload_dataset():
    from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

    payload = request.stream
    dataset = pd.read_json(payload, typ='frame', orient='split')
    FileStorage(payload).save('dataset.csv')

    return 'File Uploaded & Standing by', 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once serialized to json, your dataset is plain text. To add more parameters from there, your only options are embed your payload along with metadata in [post parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request), resulting in url-encoding the json. Or embed your payload in a top-level [json post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests), thus double-encode in json.

You would gain in clarity and maybe performance if you left json encoding job to `requests` instead. In this way you could add data and still encode/decode only once.

Example

```py
dataset = dataset.to_dict(orient='list')
post_data = {'dataset ID': "makis", 'date start': "1", 'date end': "2", 'payload': dataset}
url = "http://localhost:8081/upload_dataset"
r = requests.post(url, json=post_data)
```

Server side:

```
@app.route("/upload_dataset", methods=['POST'])
def upload_dataset():
    post_data = request.get_json()
    ## Use of meta data keys e.g. post_data['date start']
    dataset = pd.from_dict(post_data['payload'], orient='columns')
```

Comment: yup, that works just fine, thanks :). Minor correction: at the server side the first line is dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(post_data.get('dataset'), orient='columns'), whereas at the client it's dataset = dataset.to_dict(orient='list'). At least that's how i got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didnt test and assumed to_dict and to_json shared the same API, which they seem not. I made the edits