# Convert curl POST statement with JSON payload to Python request

Tags: python, api, curl, post, request

I can run this curl statemtent with curl and works perfectly. I have read many post but nothing works.

```
curl -X POST "http://some.website.com" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: Basic authcode" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"Fields\": [ \"string\" ], \"Filters\": [ { \"Field\": \"Item\", \"Operator\": \"=\", \"Value\": \"119001\" } ], \"PageSize\": 0, \"PageNumber\": 0}"
```

code tried so far

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

url = 'http://some.website.com'

headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'authorization': 'Basic authcode', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

data = {'Fields': 'string', 'Filters': { 'Field': 'Item', 'Operator': '=', 'Value': '119001' }, 'PageSize': 0, 'PageNumber': 0}

response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Error = not valid JSON Value

I have also tried

```
import simplejson as json
# ...
# ...
response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
# ...
# ...
```

Failed = Error detecting JSON fields

I think it has something to do with the nested dict statement

Comment: Can you please add full error log here. It will help finding problem.

Comment: you can convert it on https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: if you have to send json then you can use `post( ..., json=data)` instead of `post(..., data=json.dumps(data))`. And it should add automatically header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://httpbin.org/post I can see what data (headers and body) are received on server and I see the same result for `curl`

```
curl -X POST "http://httpbin.org/post" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: Basic authcode" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"Fields\": [\"string\"], \"Filters\": [{\"Field\": \"Item\", \"Operator\": \"=\", \"Value\": \"119001\"}], \"PageSize\": 0, \"PageNumber\": 0}"

# result 

{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"Fields\": [\"string\"], \"Filters\": [{\"Field\": \"Item\", \"Operator\": \"=\", \"Value\": \"119001\"}], \"PageSize\": 0, \"PageNumber\": 0}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json", 
    "Authorization": "Basic authcode", 
    "Content-Length": "122", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.58.0"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "Fields": [
      "string"
    ], 
    "Filters": [
      {
        "Field": "Item", 
        "Operator": "=", 
        "Value": "119001"
      }
    ], 
    "PageNumber": 0, 
    "PageSize": 0
  }, 
  "origin": "83.23.32.69, 83.23.32.69", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

and `Python` (using `json=data` or `data=json.dumps(data)` instead of `data=data`)

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic authcode',
#    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}

data = {
  "Fields": [ "string" ],
  "Filters": [ { "Field": "Item", "Operator": "=", "Value": "119001" } ],
  "PageSize": 0,
  "PageNumber": 0
}

response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', headers=headers, json=data)
print(response.text)

# result

{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"Fields\": [\"string\"], \"Filters\": [{\"Field\": \"Item\", \"Operator\": \"=\", \"Value\": \"119001\"}], \"PageSize\": 0, \"PageNumber\": 0}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Authorization": "Basic authcode", 
    "Content-Length": "122", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "Fields": [
      "string"
    ], 
    "Filters": [
      {
        "Field": "Item", 
        "Operator": "=", 
        "Value": "119001"
      }
    ], 
    "PageNumber": 0, 
    "PageSize": 0
  }, 
  "origin": "83.23.32.69, 83.23.32.69", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

There are only differences in headers: `"User-Agent": "curl/7.58.0"` and `"User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0"`. And Python uses `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"`.

---

**BTW:** you can use portal [curl.trillworks.com](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to convert `curl` to Python code