# How to call callback url from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa

I am trying to call a callback URL from a python function.

Here is the code:

```
rasa_url = "http://localhost:5005/webhooks/callback/webhook"
wa_data = {
    "sender":"Rasa",
    "message":"hi"
}
r = requests.post(url=rasa_url, data=wa_data)
```

In the terminal of rasa run, I am getting below error:

> sanic.exceptions.InvalidUsage: Failed when parsing body as json.

I also tried,

```
r = requests.post(url=rasa_url, data=json.loads(json.dumps(wa_data)))
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this help: [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9733638/222914)?

Comment: have you tried sending a post request using a tool like Postman ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your request does not coincide with the [documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/http-api/#operation/addConversationMessage). The only one with both sender and message i found is to:

```
http://localhost:5005/conversations/{conversation_id}/messages
```

where you can send a JSON in this format (you also have an optional `parse_data` key)

```
{
    "text": "Hello!",
    "sender": "user"
}
```