# How to execute a "curl -X POST" in python code

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to make a request, in python, from a VM running Ryu controller to a VM running a openvswitch. I've tested said request, and it works when I execute it in a terminal (a string is supposed to be returned):

```
curl -X POST -d '{"priority": 500, "match": {"in_port": 3}}' http://localhost:8080/stats/flow/8796748823560
```

This was my first try in python:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.run(['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-d', '\'{"priority": 500, "match": { "in_port": 3} }\'','http://localhost:8080/stats/flow/8796748823560'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

response = proc.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

A simple POST, as you can see. However, the response is always " ", showing the error:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Then, I decided to use the **requests** python library and wrote the POST the following way:

```
import requests

data = '{ "priority": 500, "match": {"in_port": 3}}'

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/stats/flow/234', data=data)
```

However, I don't know where to put the option **-X**. In the library documentation, I cannot find the right place to put it, if there is any.

I need help to understand where I should place that -X option in the code and, if it is not possible, how could I execute that curl on python (I was trying to avoid the `shell=True` flag on subprocess, as I don't think it is safe).

Comment: `-X POST` instructs curl to make a POST request. You're already doing that in your last approach by using `requests.post()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: You don't need the single quotes in your first attempt to use `subprocess`: subprocess.run(['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-d', '{"priority": 500, "match": { "in_port": 3} }', 'http://localhost:8080/stats/flow/8796748823560'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`. They were part of the shell syntax for specifying the JSON as a single argument, not part of the JSON itself.

Comment: Well, I though the -X option was the problem here... Because I keep getting **<Response [400]>** as the result of the above curl (using requests library)... Now I understand how that option is not needed in the code. However, how could it be that a curl executed in the terminal returns the string I want but not in the python3 code? @snwflk although it helps me understand more about the library, I tested the answer and it still returns response 400...

Comment: you can uses url https://httpbin.org/post with curl and python code and it will send back all data which it get. And then you can compare both to see differences. One of differences can be `User-Agent` header because Python sends `Python/something` and some servers automatically block it.

Comment: why do you use `"in_port": in_port` instead of `"in_port": 3` ? It can makes problem.

Comment: @furas Sorry, it was a small typo. I changed it now to  '3'. I didn't know the https://httpbin.org/post website and I found out that I could get the user-agent with https://httpbin.davecheney.com/user-agent , and so I added the right user-agent to the code. It works now, I appreciate the help!

Comment: it seems https://httpbin.davecheney.com is old version of https://httpbin.org - it even uses url `http://httpbin.org` in examples. There is also https://httpbin.org/user-agent Many pages works even if you uses incomplet User-Agent like `Mozilla/5.0`

Answer (score 1):

The `-X`/`--request` in curl is an option that is followed by the HTTP verb to be used in the request. Since this is followed by `POST` it means that a `POST` request should be used. In fact `-X POST` is not needed since the mere presence of `-d` should cause `curl` to make a HTTP POST request.

Thus, use of `request.post` with `data` containing the body should be sufficient.