# return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs) TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create an incident to the server which is hosted on another ubuntu machine.

I saved the below code as test.py file and when i execute this from a local ubuntu machine it works fine, But when i execute this from a remote aws ec2 machine, it throws error.

```
from irisclient import Irisclient
client = IrisClient(
app='oncall',
key='magic',
api_host='http://192.168.54.101:16649'
)

client.incident(plan='Oncall test', context=
{
  "description": "hello",
  "requester": "joe"
}
               )
```

error logs

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/irisclient/__init__.py", line 52, in incident
    r = self.post(self.url + 'incidents', json=incident_json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 377, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because your context data is a dict, try to convert context data to json, like this:

```
import json
from irisclient import Irisclient

client = IrisClient(
    app='oncall',
    key='magic',
    api_host='http://192.168.54.101:16649'
)

data = {
    "description": "hello",
    "requester": "joe",
}

client.incident(plan='Oncall test', context=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug in your ***irisclient*** package.  Read the traceback.  It says that on line 52 of *irisclient*/*_*_*init*_*_.py* you're calling *self.post* which is, apparently, calling some instance from the ***requests*** module ... and your irisclient code is passing a keyword argument *json=...* through that call.

But the ***requests*** library doesn't recognize this keyword argument (kwarg).  So it's throwing the *TypeError* (from line 377 of **.../requests/sessions.py**).

Perhaps you need to pass JSON through the **data=** option as described here: [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9733638/149076)

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my python to 3.5 version and it works without altering the code