# Getting JSON from http://tinywebdb.appinventor.mit.edu

Tags: python, app-inventor

I am trying to get and store JSON data from http://tinywebdb.appinventor.mit.edu from python using requests.
I am trying to have a common web DB for an android app and a desktop app.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
import requests
data = {"tag": "q1"}
r = requests.post('http://tinywebdb.appinventor.mit.edu/getvalue', params=data)
```

and then the code should return 
["VALUE","q1","999999999"]
but in JSON format

but it returns status_code 404

I am new to working with APIs so please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `data` argument, not `params`:

```
import requests
data = {"tag":"q1"}
r = requests.post('http://tinywebdb.appinventor.mit.edu/getvalue', data=data)
print(r.json())
```

output:

`['VALUE', 'q1', '999999999']`

Answer (score 1):

From [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

```
import requests
data = {"tag": "q1"}
r = requests.post('http://tinywebdb.appinventor.mit.edu/getvalue', json=data)
print(r.text)
```

gives me

```
["VALUE",null,""]
```