# receiving error 'Problems parsing JSON' when trying to comment on a pull request Using GitHub API

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api, github-api-v3

Im trying to comment on a pull request using githubs api but I'm getting the error shown in the title. The only solutions that I've seen on stack overflow is to *json.dumps* the data but that did not resolve the problem for me. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
    def _pr_comment(self, res, pr_id):
        # POST / repos /: owner /:repo / issues /: issue_number / comments

        payload = {"body": json.dumps(res)}

        header = {'Authorization': 'token TOKEN',
                  "Accept": "application/vnd.github.+json"}

        response_decoded_json = requests.post(
            f'https://api.github.com/repos/REPO/Database-System/issues/{pr_id}/comments',
            data=payload, headers=header)

        response_json = response_decoded_json.json()

        print(response_json, response_decoded_json.status_code)
```

This is the full response that I receive along side the response code

```
{'message': 'Problems parsing JSON', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment'} 400
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to use one of the github python clients rather than hitting the raw API directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing relates to the payload which was submitted.

Assuming `res` contains a string which is the actual body of the comment, I think you need to run the whole payoad through `json.dumps` then provide this as the `data` param to `requests.post`.  So change it to something like:

```
payload = json.dumps({"body": res})
```

The [requests documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.0-0/user/advanced/#http-verbs) actually contains an example, related to the github API.

Comment: @sharjeel Probably worth reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315/2052575) also.  As of requests `v2.4.2` you can pass a `json` parameter, which makes requests handle the encoding.  This can simply be passed a dict: `requests.post(url, json={'body':res})`