# how to again post a file that is received in a post request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, post, file-upload

When I am trying to post the file that I have received from a post request, it is giving me an error as:

expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage

How am I suppose to post the file?
A proper syntax is what I am looking for.
However without posting file, that is only posting data is working fine.

```
from PIL import Image
from flask_restful import Resource, request, Api
import requests

class fileSendingApi(Resource):
    def post(self):
          images=open(request.files['my_image_1'],'rb')
          URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/final_img_api'
          file={"my_image_2": images}
          values={"auth_key": "some_auth_key"}
          response = requests.post(URL, files=file, data=values)
          output = response.json()
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code:

> `images=open(request.files['my_image_1'],'rb')`

When using open you are actually transforming the file from web-uploaded file to `FileStorage`.
What you want to do is use the file that was uploaded:
`images=request.files['my_image_1']`
and it should work.

By the way, if you want to save the image use: `images.save(FILE_PATH)` instead of `open()`