# How to make a API call using requests in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm a newbie in python and I'm dealing with this problem, I want to make an API POST request by using Python but I can't send a request with this. Can anyone help me figure it out? This is what I have:

```
import requests

headers = {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = 
{
    "token": "TokenStaging",
    "OrderCode": "23FNQY46"
}
r = requests.post('https://dev-online-gateway.ghn.vn/apiv3-api/api/v1/apiv3/OrderInfo',
    headers=headers, data=data)
```

API document link: https://api.ghn.vn/home/docs/detail?id=29#parameter-examples-APIV3-OrderInfo-1_0_0-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Comment: Your `headers` are a set instead of a dict - format it the same way as `data`.

Comment: There's an issue with the headers object. You misquoted the strings, so it's a set instead of a dict. Use this: `headers = {'Accept': application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`.

Comment: @farincz I tried but get the 400 ERROR CODE :(

Comment: I tried all of you guys solution but still get that 400 error code

Comment: There's something wrong with the endpoint. I get `{"code":0,"msg":"An error occured","data":{"decode":"invalid character \'o\' in literal true (expecting \'r\')"}}` in response. Changing `"token":` to `"taken":` in `data` produces `{"code":0,"msg":"An error occured","data":{"decode":"invalid character \'a\' in literal true (expecting \'r\')"}}` in response. The endpoint isn't parsing `data` correctly.

Comment: Do token and OrderCode parameters have valid values? Try to print some additional info from the response to start debugging it This one could help you get more detail
**print(r.text)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and testing, i finally can call that API with this :

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://console.ghn.vn/api/v1/apiv3/OrderInfo',
 json={
  "token": "TokenStaging",
  "OrderCode": "23FNQY46"
})
```

Thank you guys for all your support