# How can I send this request using python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

How to send the below request using python requests library?

Request :

> [image: request]

I have tried

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    // Some login action

    url = f'http://somewebsite.com/lib/ajax/service.php?key={key}&info=get_enrolled'
    json_data = {
        "index": 0,
        "methodname": "get_enrolled",
        // And so on, from Request Body
    }

    r = session.post(url, json=json_data)
```

But it doesn't give the output I want.

Comment: images do not help can you post the text.

Comment: Could be you need to replicate one or more of the headers. `session.post` takes a `headers` argument (a `dict`) I think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post JSON using Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests)

Answer (score 0):

1.Define a POST request method

```
import urllib3
import urllib.parse

def request_with_url(url_str, parameters=None):
    """
    https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html
    """
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    response = http.request("POST",
                            url_str, 
                            headers={ 
                                'Content-Type' : 'application/json' 
                            },
                            body=parameters)
    resp_data = str(response.data, encoding="utf-8")
    return resp_data
```

2.Call the function with your specific url and parameters

```
json_data = {
        "index": 0,
        "methodname": "get_enrolled",
        // And so on, from Request Body
    }
key = "123456"
url = "http://somewebsite.com/lib/ajax/service.php?key={0}&info=get_enrolled".format(key)

request_with_url(url, json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

With no more info what you want and from what url it is hard to help but.
But try adding headers with the user-agent to the post. More headers may be needed, but User-Agent is a header that is often required.

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    // Some login action

    url = f'http://somewebsite.com/lib/ajax/service.php?key={key}&info=get_enrolled'
    json_data = {
        "index": 0,
        "methodname": "get_enrolled",
        // And so on, from Request Body
    }
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = session.post(url, json=json_data, headers=headers)
```