# Convert CURL request to python 3

Tags: python, curl

I have this curl request I would like to convert to python  3

```
curl -X "POST" "https://conversations.messagebird.com/v1/send" \\
-H "Authorization: AccessKey YOUR-API-KEY" \\
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \\
--data '{ "to":"+31XXXXXXXXX", "from":"WHATSAPP-CHANNEL-ID", "type":"text", "content":{ "text":"Hello!" }, "reportUrl":"https://example.com/reports" }'
```

can anyone help me please?

I've tried the following request, but not working :

```
import requests

header = {"Authorization":"AccessKey YOUR-API-KEY"}
data = { "to":"+31XXXXXXXXX", "from":"WHATSAPP-CHANNEL-ID", "type":"text", "content":{"text":"Hello!" },  "reportUrl":"https://example.com/reports"}
url = 'https://conversations.messagebird.com/v1/send'
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
print(response.text)
```

I'm having the error message :

```
<Response [400]>
{"errors":[{"code":21,"description":"JSON is not a valid format"}]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use json instead of data,

```
requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json={"key": "value"})
```

2. you need dump data

```
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

3. thers is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9733638/15073910) like yours.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [documentation](https://developers.messagebird.com/quickstarts/whatsapp/send-your-first-whatsapp-message-curl/), the cURL is correct and would be implemented as is in Python:

```
import requests

header = {
    "Authorization": "AccessKey YOUR-API-KEY", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = {
    "to": "+31XXXXXXXXX", 
    "from": "WHATSAPP-CHANNEL-ID", 
    "type": "text", 
    "content": {"text":"Hello!"}, 
    "reportUrl": "https://example.com/reports"
}
url = 'https://conversations.messagebird.com/v1/send'
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=header)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: sure, can you please accept it as the correct answer if it solved your issue