# Yet again: "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list" in requests library

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm writing som simple request and just can't understant what's wrong

```
data1 = df.loc[N, 'online_raw_json']
print(type(data1))
print(data1)
data1 = json.dumps(data1)
print(type(data1))
print(data1)

response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", json=data1)
print(response.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<class 'str'>
{"batch_id": 230866, "heat_no": "2019333", "tasks":7, "oxy": 41.6, ... "data": []}]}
<class 'str'>
"{\"batch_id\": 230866, \"heat_no\": \"2019333\", \"tasks\": 7, ... \"data\": []}]}"
```

So I get error
**Exception happened in API function: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list**

json.dumps must provide "proper" json, but still it is treated like a string.

Comment: Show the full stacktrace

Comment: You already have a string, so `json.dumps(data1)` is double-stringing your data

Comment: What is full stacktace?

Comment: Besides that, requests can accept a dictionary for the `json` parameter https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315/2308683

Comment: Don't copy the only error message. Copy the full output, that shows exactly what module and code line throws the exception

Comment: That's all I got in pycharm. If I print(response), I get  <Response [500]>.
This is a request to a bentoml service (bentoml serve /path/)

Comment: I don't know what bentoml is. You seem to be calling some localhost server endpoint, which you'd have full logs for. In other words, what is returning the text "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list"? And that appears to be a Python exception message, so you're getting a traceback that shows exactly where the issue is... In particular, focus on why it thinks your JSON is actually a list type

Comment: It's best to pass a normal Python object as the json argument, because that way requests will not only handle serialisation, it will also set the correct Content-Type header.

Comment: OneCricketeer, you were right. I found the error. It's working now with just a dict, instead of a json-string-construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps` is meant to 'dump' a python Dict as a `str`. So [it's working as intended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

In your case you should parse the string to a dict, with `json.loads(data1)` for example.

```
data1 = df.loc[N, 'online_raw_json']
data1 = json.loads(data1)

response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", json=data1)
print(response.text)
```