# facebook messenger curl request returns <Response [400]>

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I am new to the messenger API, I want to send a message using a curl post request, this is my code:

```
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN = an Active access token

fb_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/messages"
data = {
'recipient': '{"id":4098757906843152}',
"message": {
"text": "hello, world!"
},
"messaging_type": "MESSAGE_TAG",
"tag": "ACCOUNT_UPDATE"
}

params = {'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN}
resp = requests.post(fb_url, params=params, data=data)
print(resp)
```

unfortunately, I got this message <Response [400]>
any help would be appreciated

Comment: And what is the response body?

Comment: Does Python automatically convert your dictionary to JSON?

Comment: Also I'm not sure `'{"id":4098757906843152}'` should be wrapped in single-quote

Comment: @WizKid <Response [400]>

Comment: @AndrewL no it does not, but do I need JSON here?

Comment: @AndrewL did that but nothing changed

Comment: <Response [400]> is not the response body. There should be one.

Comment: Can you try reproducing the call using FB Graph Explorer Tool. There's an option to convert it to Curl using "Get Code" button in bottom right, copy/paste raw curl here after https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: @WizKid well, I cant find it

Comment: @AndrewL here it is:
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/resp = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/messages", params= {'access_token': "token"}, data={     'recipient': {"id":'4098757906843152'},     "message": {     "text": "hello, world!"     },     "messaging_type": "MESSAGE_TAG",     "tag": "ACCOUNT_UPDATE" })?access_token=token"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `data` to `json`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315/603756

> Starting with Requests version 2.4.2, you can use the json= parameter (which takes a dictionary) instead of data= (which takes a string) in the call

```
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN = '<access_token>'

fb_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/messages'
data = {
    'recipient': '{"id":<psid>}',
    "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
    }
}
params = {'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN}

resp = requests.post(fb_url, json=data, params=params)
print(resp)
```

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, thank you very much.