# I cant send a form/data with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to send an email and a password through a POST, but the way I'm doing it in the code below it's not working.
How could I do this correctly?

```
import requests
inf = '{"user_email": "celes.....bosa@gmail.com", "user_password": "xxxxxxxxx"}'
z = requests.post('https://www.iped.com.br/api/user/login', data=inf)
print(z)
print(z.json())
```

Comment: try `inf = {"user_email": "celes.....bosa@gmail.com", "user_password": "xxxxxxxxx"}
requests.post('https://www.iped.com.br/api/user/login', json=inf)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to let `inf` as a `dict` in order to send it using `data=` parameter.

Check the help for `requests.post`:

```
post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)
Sends a POST request.

:param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
:param data: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
    object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
:param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
:param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
:return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
:rtype: requests.Response
```

Make sure to check also this: [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)