# Azure DevOps Python {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: q. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n"}}

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops

Trying to get Work Items for an Azure DevOps Project.

```
import requests
import base64
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.devops.v5_1.work_item_tracking.models import Wiql
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication


organization = "https://dev.azure.com/dev"
pat = 'ey3nbq'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

payload = {
 
  "query": "SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse') AND ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story') MODE (DoesNotContain)"
}


response = requests.post(url="https://dev.azure.com/dev/Agile_Board/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1", headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Gives response 400

Have tried many things, been struggling a bit with this. Any help is much appreciated. How to get project's work items without using their `ID` . Does the `request` need to be changed in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your post to (json=payload):

```
response = requests.post(url="https://dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORG/Agile_Board/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1", headers=headers, json=payload)
```

or use something like this:

```
payload_str = "{\"query\": \"SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse') AND ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story') MODE (DoesNotContain)\"}"

response = requests.post(url="https://dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORG/Agile_Board/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1", headers=headers, data=payload_str)
```

Check this question: [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)