# How to create a post request in python with payload request?

Tags: python, json, post, get, request

I want to create a post request like the following picture in python that return data as I received in a browser :

[image]

And cookie is as follow:
[image]
For this, I have written the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://flight-api-v1.utravs.com/Flight/statistic/FlightPriceStatistics"
data = {
    "minimumPriceStatisticRequest": {
        "$id": 1,
        "availabilityRequest": {
            "$id": 2,
            "segments": {
                "$id": 3,
                "$values": [
                    {
                        "$id": 4,
                        "destination": "KIH-Kish-all",
                        "origin": "THR-Tehran-all",
                        "departureDateTime": "2021-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "uniqueIndex": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            "passengers": {
                "$id": 5,
                "$values": [
                    {
                        "$id": 6,
                        "type": 1,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "optionalServices": {
                            "$id": 7,
                            "$values": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "travelDetails": {
                "$id": 8,
                "cabinType": 1,
                "airTripType": 1,
                "stopQuantityType": 3,
                "pricingSourceType": 3
            },
            "availabilityType": 0
        },
        "minRange": 10,
        "maxRange": 10
    }
}
x = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(x.text)
```

But I don't receive the right information from the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)

Comment: @vinzBad Unfortunately, No. u can test it in python. the site is online.

Comment: please try requests.post(url, json=data)

Comment: I get a SessionAccessDenied Error when posting with json=data, probably your code is missing some authentication step. You can try transplanting the cookies from your browser request.

Comment: Looks like you need to provide some kind of credentials. I tried your code and get HTTP 200 but with this text "{"Success":false,"FailedReason":23,"Error":{"Code":23,"Message":"There is no error description available for SessionAccessDenied","HaveToBlockCredit":false},"Validations":[]}"

Comment: @DarkKnight So, what should I do?

Comment: You'll need to review the documentation for that API

Comment: @DarkKnight But I can browse by a browser without any credentials!

Comment: @DarkKnight I want to crawl this page.

Comment: @vinzBad I added the cookie picture in the post. please tell me what should I do?

Comment: If you try to use that URL in a browser you will get a different error. Try it in something like Postman and you'll see the error

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes. you are right. But when I paste the URL in browser it send a get request instead of a POST.

Comment: please redact the cookie values as they contain potential sensitive info

Comment: Of course the browser issues a GET but you said "But I can browse by a browser..." which has nothing to do with issuing a POST. I was merely pointing out that you can **not** do this via a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to post an `application/json` request so use the `json` parameter for `requests.post()`
2. the api you're communicating with seems to require some sort of authentication, try to transplant the session cookie with the `cookies` parameter

   ```
   data = {...}
   cookies = {"_session": "1ac[..]"}
   response = requests.post(url, json=data, cookies=cookies)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what you want:

```
import requests

url = "https://flight-api-v1.utravs.com/Flight/statistic/FlightPriceStatistics"
data = {
    "minimumPriceStatisticRequest": {
        "$id": 1,
        "availabilityRequest": {
            "$id": 2,
            "segments": {
                "$id": 3,
                "$values": [
                    {
                        "$id": 4,
                        "destination": "KIH-Kish-all",
                        "origin": "THR-Tehran-all",
                        "departureDateTime": "2021-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "uniqueIndex": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            "passengers": {
                "$id": 5,
                "$values": [
                    {
                        "$id": 6,
                        "type": 1,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "optionalServices": {
                            "$id": 7,
                            "$values": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "travelDetails": {
                "$id": 8,
                "cabinType": 1,
                "airTripType": 1,
                "stopQuantityType": 3,
                "pricingSourceType": 3
            },
            "availabilityType": 0
        },
        "minRange": 10,
        "maxRange": 10
    }
}
with requests.Session() as session:
    cookies = {"_session": "1acda9e8-3051-47bb-bddf-9d68553ebbee"}
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    (x := session.post(url, json=data, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
    print(x.json()['Result'])
```

Note: The session cookie used in this answer may expire. So, although it works now, it may not always work