# how to translate curl_setopt_array from php to python code?

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, web-services

problem:

1. How to translate curl_setopt_array from PHP to Python
2. I want to use the webservice using python, I got this code in PHP

My environment:

- Python 3.9
- Windows 11

PHP code:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'api_key' => 'APIKEY',
    'sender'  => '6285157853022',
    'number'  => '082136815088',
    'message' => 'the message'
];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://wa.mydomain.id/wa/app/api/send-message",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data))
);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

and I got success response

```
{"status":true,"msg":"Message sent successfully"}
```

I was trying this code in python:

```
import requests
import json

data = {
    'api_key': 'APIKEY',
    'sender': '6285157853022',
    'number': '082136815088',
    'message': 'the message'
}

response = requests.post('http://wa.mydomain.id/wa/app/api/send-message', data=data)
print(response.text)
```

and I got this response

```
{"status":false,"msg":"Incorrect parameters!"}
```

how to fix it? thanks for helping me.

**tried solutions:**

1. I tried sending the data with headers but still doesn't work

The code:

```
import requests

url = "http://wa.mydomain.id/wa/app/api/send-message"

payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'api_key': 'APIKEY',
  'sender': '6285157853022',
  'number': '6282136815088',
  'message': 'hi'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Result:

```
{"status":false,"msg":"Incorrect parameters!"}
```

2. I tried this solution ([How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)) but still doesn't work

The code :

```
import requests
import json

data = {
    'api_key': 'APIKEY',
    'sender': '6285157853022',
    'number': '082136815088',
    'message': 'the message'
}

response = requests.post('http://wa.mydomain.id/wa/app/api/send-message', json=data)
print(response.text)
```

the result:

```
{"status":false,"msg":"Incorrect parameters!"}
```

Comment: Don't post your api keys here. they will be missused

Comment: ok thanks, I changed the API keys

Comment: try sending the data as headers maybe? is there any form of documentation for this api?

Comment: I don't have any documentation for this API, still, I got this response if I use to send the data as headers {"status":false,"msg":"Incorrect parameters!"}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)

Comment: still the same i got {"status":false,"msg":"Incorrect parameters!"}, i was trying that solution with this code : data = {
    'api_key': 'APIKEY',
    'sender': '6285157853022',
    'number': '082136815088',
    'message': 'the message'
}

response = requests.post('http://wa.mydomain.id/wa/app/api/send-message', json=data)
print(response.text)