# Problem with a requests to couchdb database

Tags: python, python-requests, couchdb

I am trying to send data to a couchdb database using POST request with python requests library. But there is a problem, when I execute the script this error appears : {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
And here is the code :

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> import couchdb
>>> url = 'http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/db_reviewin'
>>> headers = {'Content-type':'application/json'}
>>> payload = {"key":"value"}
>>> res = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=payload)
>>> print(res.text)
```

If you have any idea, tell me ! Thanks and have a good day/night

Comment: `data` expects a string type, use `json=payload`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)