# post requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I want to do a post request in python with basic authentication AND token. I have already tested the post in postman and it worked but with python I always get status code 403.

For this API I have to do...

- first fetch a token from the header with a GET request
- use this token in header for POST request

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('User', 'Password')

token = requests.get(URL_token, auth=auth, headers={"x-csrf-token":"FETCH"}).headers['x-csrf-token']

requests.post(POST_url, data=json.dumps(test_data), headers={"x-csrf-token":token}, auth=auth)
```

The test_data are type of a list and again, in postman it works.

Is there something which I am doing wrong in the POST?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST JSON data with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do every step within a `requests.Session()`:

```
s = requests.Session()
token = s.get(get_test_token, auth=auth, headers={"x-csrf-token":"FETCH"}).headers['x-csrf-token']
s.post(get_test_token, json=test_data, headers={"x-csrf-token":token}, auth=auth)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, your JSON payload as the body, but you're passing it `data` which is used for form data.

Therefore, try changing this line

```
requests.post(POST_url, data=json.dumps(test_data), headers={"x-csrf-token":token}, auth=auth)
```

to

```
requests.post(POST_url, json=test_data, headers={"x-csrf-token":token}, auth=auth)
```

Comment: requests.post does not have the keyword `body`

Comment: Extremely sorry, my bad, I mixed up between scrapy and requests, corrected it now.

Comment: the error code 403 still exists

Comment: 403 means Forbidden, then you need to check if you're passing headers correctly like Bearer token and CSRF token, and anything else which is needed.