# Python login using RestApi requests module

Tags: python, rest, authentication, curl

I cannot force the Python requests module to work with my server for authentication. First, the user has to authenticate to get the token to work with other GET requests.
On the other hand, when I use CURL request everything works just fine. I cannot see where I'm missing something so maybe someone is able to point me in the right direction.

CURL request (working and code 200):
`curl -X 'POST' -k 'https://myserver/login' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"Username": "myuser","Password": "mypassword","InactivityTimeout": 1}'`

Python code that isn't working (code 400):

```
#!/bin/python3.9
import requests

site_url = 'https://myserver/login'
login_info = {'Username': 'myuser', 'Password': 'mypassword', 'InactivityTimeout': 1}
site_headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
sess = requests.session()
login_resp = sess.post(site_url, data=login_info, headers=site_headers, verify=False)
print(login_resp)
```

I tried to change the order of parameters but without any success. Also double-checked any typos and briefly checked the documentation of resources but still nothing. I'm getting the self-signed error when trying to connect so that's why I'm skipping security check in both requests.

Comment: What happens if you pass your `login_info` dictionary in the `json=` argument, rather than in `data=`, as explained in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344315) ?

Comment: it's humiliating but it works... no idea how I missed that. Thank you...