CVAT API called from python requests give "Multipart form parse error"
I'm trying to upload .xml-annotations into cvat by using python script with requests module.
My code:
with open('../metadata_decompressed/1770.xml/annotations_copy.xml', 'rb') as f:
    #data = f.read()
    req = requests.post('https://*cvat-server-here*/api/tasks/1770/annotations/?location=local&use_default_location=false',
    data={'annotation_file': f}, 
    auth=('*cvat-user-here*','*cvat_password-here*')
    headers={
        'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'
    })

But I get status code 400 and this in the response body:
{"detail":"Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"}
What do I do wrong?
P.S. Added boundary:
headers={
        'Content-type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
    }

Get new error now:
400
"No such file were uploaded"

Changed code to:
with open('../metadata_decompressed/1770.xml/annotations_copy.xml', 'rb') as f:
    #data = f.read()
    req = requests.post('https://*cvat-server-here*/api/tasks/1770/annotations/?location=local&use_default_location=false',
    files={'annotation_file': f}, 
    auth=('*cvat-user-here*','*cvat_password-here*')
    )

Get this 400-code again.
With JSON-content-type:
with open('../metadata_decompressed/1770.xml/annotations_copy.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    req = requests.post('https://*cvat-server-here*/api/tasks/1770/annotations/?location=local&use_default_location=false',
    json={'annotation_file': data}, 
    auth=('*cvat-user-here*','*cvat_password-here*'),
    headers={
        'Content-type':'application/json'
    }
    )

{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}

The Content-Type header needs to include the used boundary that separates the parts from each other, but with your current code, you are not including any. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12385179/1427878

@C3roe thanks. Looked for it and added something. Got new error.

And where did you get that boundary value from?

@C3roe as I understood, I need to put something which will not match anything in the file because I'm sending only one file. So I just put something like this. Was I wrong?

The actual request body must contain this boundary value, even if there is only one "part" - you can not just make up an arbitrary value and stick that into the header. The linked question has multiple approaches.

@C3roe thanks for clarification. Changed the code, so it should set the boundary automatically now. but still get the error.

The endpoint you are using there appears to be https://docs.cvat.ai/docs/api_sdk/sdk/reference/apis/tasks-api/#create_annotations ? I don't see any actual file upload going on with the parameters listed there - if anything, it appears to accept a filename parameter that is supposed to be a string value.

@C3roe Here it is: https://app.cvat.ai/api/docs/#tag/tasks/operation/tasks_create_annotations

The endpoint accepts JSON as well, which could avoid any such issues. If you want to keep using multipart/formdata, then you'll have to figure out how to make such a request correctly, with the library you're using there.

@C3roe updated question. I tried JSON but it gives an error too. But different. I thought that json can be compatible with annotations formats contained in json-format. Not in xml like "cvat 1.1".

That probably isn't converting your data into JSON, just because you set the Content-Type header. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9733638/1427878

@C3roe edited to 'json={'annotation_file': data}'. Same error.

Maybe you should try and get the request working using a tool like postman first. Right now, it's hard to tell if the problem is with the structure of what you are sending, or how you are sending it.
