# Updating records with Python 3 through API on Rails 4 application

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, api, python-3.x, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4 / mongoid application which needs to expose APIs for other applications and scripts. I need to be able to update documents in one of the models through an API with Python 3 script. I'm a bit fresh with Python hence asking for help here.

I already found out how to query Rails APIs with Python 3 and urllib but struggling with updates. I was trying to go through Python 3.5 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) for urllib2 but struggling to apply this to my script.

What goes to `data` and how to add authentication token to `headers`, which in `curl` would look something like this

```
-H 'Authorization:Token token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"'
-X POST -d "name=A60E001&status=changed"
```

I would greatly appreciate if somebody explained how to, for example, update `status` based on `name` (name is not unique yet but will be). My biggest challenge is the Python side. Once I have the data in params on Rails side I think I can handle it. I think.

I included my model and update action from the controller below.

`app/models/experiment.rb`

```
class Experiment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :status, type:String
end
```

`app/controllers/api/v1/experiments_controller.rb`

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ExperimentsController < ActionController::Base
      before_filter :restrict_access

      ...

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @expt_proc.update(expt_proc_params)
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @expt_proc }
         else
            format.json { render json: @expt_proc.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      ...

    private
      def restrict_access
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
          ApiKey.where(access_token: token).exists?
        end
      end
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out who to  send a PATCH request with Python 3 and update the the record's `status` by `name`.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853050/how-do-i-make-a-patch-request-in-python#answer-7112444) post found out about `requests` module. I used [requests.patch](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) to update the record and it works great.

`python code`

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/update_expt_queue.json'
payload = {'expt_name' : 'myExperiment1', 'status' : 'finished' }

r = requests.patch(url, payload)
```

There are two problems remaining:

1. How to add headers to this request which would allow me to go through token based authentication. At the moment it's disabled. [request.patch](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.patch) only takes 2 parameters, it doesn't take `headers` parameter.
2. How to access the JSON which is sent in response by Rails API.